API Issues H- I query from API Explorer, my ContactGroups is an empty array in each of my contact. Is it an API faulty?
I have a question about the API stuffs.
I have added contacts into Group in Xero admin site.
But when I query from API Explorer, my ContactGroups is an empty array in each of my contact.
Is it an API faulty?
May I Know how to overcome this issues. Please advise.

Please post a minimal code example, so that readers can assess whether the code is faulty, or maybe reproduce a problem on the server.

If you make a GET contacts request the response is a summary response.
If you GET contacts with paging or make a GET request to the individual contact then full details will be returned.
To utilise paging, append a page parameter to the URL e.g. ?page=1. If there are 100 records in the response you will need to check if there is any more data by fetching the next page e.g ?page=2 and continuing this process until no more results are returned.
